# Каким образом нужно написать unit-тест для загрузки файлов на сервер в YII2?

Tags: php, yii2, юнит-тесты, fileupload, codeception

Пытаюсь написать unit-тест для проверки загрузки файлов на сервер в Yii2 приложении используя Codeception.
Есть модель Images:

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "images".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $good_id
 * @property string $path
 * @property string $image_name
 */
class Images extends ActiveRecord
{
    public $img;
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'images';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['good_id'], 'integer'],
            [['img'], 'file', 'extensions' => ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'], 'maxSize' => Yii::$app->params['maxImageSize']],
            [['image_name', 'alt'], 'string', 'max' => 255]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'good_id' => 'Good ID',
            'image_name' => 'Image Name',
        ];
    }

    public function getGood()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Goods::className(),['good_id' => 'good_id'])->inverseOf('images');
    }

    public static function deleteAll($condition = '', $params = [])
    {
        $files = self::find()
            ->select(['good_id', 'image_name'])
            ->where($condition)
            ->asArray()
            ->all();

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $file_name = Yii::$app->params['goodsImagePath'] . $file['good_id'] . '/' . $file['image_name'];

            if ($file['image_name'] && file_exists($file_name)) {
                unlink($file_name);
            }
        }

        return parent::deleteAll($condition, $params);
    }

    public function save($runValidation = true, $attributeNames = null)
    {
        $dir = Yii::$app->params['goodsImagePath'] . $this->good_id . '/';
        if ($this->img) {

            if ($this->image_name) {
                $file = $dir . $this->image_name;

                if (file_exists($file)) {
                    unlink($file);
                }
            }

            $this->image_name = uniqid() . '.' . $this->img->extension;
            $this->img->saveAs($dir . $this->image_name);
        }

        return parent::save($runValidation, $attributeNames);
    }
}
```

параметр `'goodsImagePath'` имеет значение `'../../frontend/web/uploads/goods/'`

нужно написать Unit-тест для проверки сохранения файла на сервер.
Если пытаться создать свой объект класса `UploadedFile` как через конструктор, так и через `getInstance()`, то файл не сохранится на сервере. Все из-за того, что в приложении есть Post переменная `$_FILES`, а в тесте она не определена. Скорее всего из-за этого файл не сохраняется на сервер.

Пример моего unit-теста, который не работает:

```
public function testUploadFile()
{
    $image = new UploadedFile([
      'name' => 'test_picture3.png',
      'tempName' => \Yii::getAlias('@tests/codeception/common/unit/files/test_picture3.png'),
      'type' => 'image/png',
      'size' => 84.71 * 1024]);;
    $model = new Images([
        'id' => '2001',
        'good_id' => 1001,
        'image_name' => $image->name,
        'img' => $image,
    ]);
    expect('File uploaded successfully', $model->validate())->true();
    expect('File saved to server successfully', $model->save())->true();
    $this->assertFileExists(Yii::getAlias('@app_configs/') . Yii::$app->params['goodsImagePath'] . $model->good_id . '/' . $model->image_name, "File should be exist in 'Uploads' directory ");

}
```

либо второй вариант:

```
public function testUploadCorrectFile()
{
    $model = new Images([
      'id' => '2001',
      'good_id' => 1001,
      'image_name' => 'test_picture1.jpg',
    ]);
    $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'img');

    $image->tempName = '' ;
    $image->name = 'test_picture1.jpg';
    $image->tempName = \Yii::getAlias('@tests/codeception/common/unit/files/test_picture1.jpg');
    $image->type = 'image/jpeg';
    $image->size = 84.71 * 1024;

    $model->good_id = 1001;
    $model->id = '2001';
    $model->image_name = $image->name;

    expect('File uploaded successfully', $model->validate())->true();
    expect('File saved to server successfully', $model->save())->true();
    $this->assertFileExists(Yii::getAlias('@app_configs/') . Yii::$app->params['goodsImagePath'] . $model->good_id . '/' . $model->image_name, "File should be exist in 'Uploads' directory ");
}
```

Файл не сохраняется на сервер.
Как правильно нужно проверять загрузку файлов в unit-тесте?

Comment: Как вариант: переопределить класс `UploadedFile` для теста